# Is the diner slang in this scene real?

Tags: nutrition, television

In an episode of Spongebob Squarepants, a character orders the following:

> I'll take a Double Triple Bossy Deluxe on a raft, 4x4 animal style, extra shingles with a shimmy and a squeeze, light axle grease; make it cry, burn it, and let it swim.

It's widely circulated that this slang is not simply nonsense but translates to a ridiculously large sandwich to the point where Youtuber Binging with Babish [actually made it](https://youtu.be/Y8hi6A5MPVY)

Obviously nowhere would serve this monstrosity but is it true that the order would actually make sense?

Comment: Not sure if this is a joke, but if questions about cartoons are real will be on-topic here, I don't know what could ever be deleted.

Comment: @pipe There was a question about whether the comedy trope of banana skins was a thing- this is in the same vein.

Comment: The video's intro briefly credits a Reddit user called "Boothin" with "translating" the order, but I can't see a link in the video notes or recipe. Perhaps that post could be tracked down and quoted to provide a more direct claim to examine.

Comment: In fact, it seems like [that user disclaims credit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/9tyl5t/comment/e90iv7m/), tracing the interpretation back to 4chan. That's as far into the bowels of the internet as I'm willing to venture; someone with a stronger stomach might want to venture back further and find the actual post; or, there's a screenshot in that post that someone could transcribe.

Comment: @ComicSansStrikephim Maybe there is a claim somewhere but you don't mention any.

Comment: @pipe: This is the [canonical meta-question](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/random-claims-from-fantasy-stories-and-movies) on the topic of whether to accept claims from fiction.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'll take a...

- Double Triple (["Super Double Triple Patty"](https://www.facebook.com/NickelodeonAustralia/videos/the-customer-is-always-right-scene-spongebob/235180971965680/) is on the menu, or possibly it's asking for two "triples", which would have 3 patties each)
- Bossy ([beef](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/ljhrxma))
- Deluxe (double the grease, according to [Greasy Buffoons](https://spongebob.fandom.com/wiki/Greasy_Buffoons); meaning varies in the real world: [Subway](https://www.msn.com/en-us/foodanddrink/foodnews/what-is-deluxe-style-at-subway/ar-AA16bPE6), [McDonald's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonald%27s_Deluxe_line))
- on a raft, ([toast](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/f5ma5di))
- 4x4 (["four patties and four slices of cheese"](https://books.google.com/books?id=2F0EAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA41&dq=%224x4%22%20patties%20cheese&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN4aD7y7j_AhWvGFkFHad2B7UQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%224x4%22%20patties%20cheese&f=false))
- animal style, (["mustard fried on the patty, double sauce, pickles and grilled onions"](https://books.google.com/books?id=-f0DAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA30&dq=%22animal%20style%22%20sandwich&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkp_ehy7j_AhWdEVkFHQWsC-QQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=%22animal%20style%22%20sandwich&f=false))
- extra shingles (extra [toast](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/vzng2za))
- with a shimmy ([jam](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Practically_Useless_Information_on_Food/qjrKELUcaPYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=shimmy)/[jelly](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/cmo3jki))
- and a squeeze, (some [type of -ade](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Listening_to_America/TS2DlLXmen0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22a%20squeeze%22%20%22lemonade%22%20slang&dq=%22a%20squeeze%22%20%22lemonade%22%20slang&printsec=frontcover), maybe [lemonade](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Druggists_Circular/bG0gAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22a%20squeeze%22%20))
- light axle grease; (light [butter](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Practically_Useless_Information_on_Food/qjrKELUcaPYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22make%20it%20cry%22%20sandwich&pg=PA94&printsec=frontcover))
- make it cry, ([add onion](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Practically_Useless_Information_on_Food/qjrKELUcaPYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22make%20it%20cry%22%20sandwich&pg=PA94&printsec=frontcover))
- burn it, and let it swim. ([an ice cream float](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Wizard_of_Food_s_Encyclopedia_of_Kit/I5FVn9EjHH0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22let%20it%20swim%22))

The beginning in particular is a bit of a stretch to reality, but (as various sources note) "4x4 animal style" is directly lifted from the ["secret" menu at In-N-Out Burger](https://www.in-n-out.com/menu/not-so-secret-menu). Also, "squeeze" may be a mistake; ["shingle[s] with a shimmy and a shake"](https://books.google.com/books?id=T45vDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT170&dq=shingle%20%22a%20shimmy%20and%20a%20shake%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDmYqK87j_AhVfjIkEHUXlBoQQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=shingle%20%22a%20shimmy%20and%20a%20shake%22&f=false) collocates much better (buttered toast with jam).

Comment: Now that's the kind of research this site can be proud of.

Comment: Could you add descriptions for each of your links? At the moment, it's hard to get an idea of how authoritative they are without clicking every single one. It's also notable that a couple of your interpretations are different from those presented on 4chan/Reddit/YouTube (see my comments under the question about tracing the origins of this "recipe").

Comment: @ComicSansStrikephim I wouldn't be so hasty. The interpretation of "squeeze" as "lemonade" in between a bunch of burger ingredients seems particularly dubious to me. The 4chan interpretation is some kind of sauce, which makes more sense.

Comment: Is this meant to be one dish or a set? An ice cream float mixed in burger is as dubious as adding lemonade..

Comment: At least one of your links is duplicated, leaving "light axle grease" unsourced; since you seem to have declined my suggestion of labelling the sources, I'm not sure if the others are all valid. Apart from that, this seems to be an attempt at original research into the possible meaning, rather than an examination of the evidence for the version quoted in the question. In other words, it's a fun piece of fan analysis, but I don't think it qualifies as a good answer on this site.

Comment: Double triple is In-n-Out code for a double burger with triple cheese. It sounds like this is the first burger and 4x4... is the second burger.  This is also similar (and maybe a shout-out for) the banter/specification of hash browns at Waffle House.